# is it possible to change style of navigation modules in swiper js?

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I am trying out swiper JS for carousel in my Vue project,and want to change the style of navigation modules. How do I alter the look of the swiper module?

Comment: Find the proper CSS class and style it with CSS.